# Django ajax file upload form - file not uploading

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a file upload form in html with which I'm trying to upload a file(and file size to display) via ajax call. I'm using django. Whenever I try to do anything nothing happens. Here's the upload form:

```
<form class="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" id="uploadFile">
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="uploadButton" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here's my Jquery + Ajax:

```
$('.uploadForm').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var fileSize = ($('#uploadFile')[0].files[0].size/1024);
  var fileName = $('#uploadFile')[0].files[0].name;
  var realSize = sizeConverter(fileSize);
  var fileData = new FormData($('#uploadFile')[0]);
  var csrfToken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'project:uploadFile' %}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      'fileData': fileData,
      'fileSize': realSize,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
     },
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Here are views.py:

```
class uploadFile(TemplateView):
template_name = "project/uploadFile.html"

def post(self, request):
    fileSize = request.POST.get('fileSize')
    fileData = request.FILES['fileData']
    return JsonResponse(fileSize, safe=False)
```

Now, with this setup when I submit the form nothing happens. I don't get any errors in the console, nothing.
When I remove `'fileData'` from data and `cache: false, processData: false, contentType: false,` inside Ajax this works(text only though).
I tried changing `new FormData($('#uploadFile')[0]);` to `new FormData($('#uploadFile').get(0));` but that did not help. I am guessing the issue here is with the fileData variable but what could be wrong with it? I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in your javascript, try to change `'csrfmiddlewaretoken'`

Comment: When I do this I get "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)"

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation on [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), the correct approach would be in the sense of:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileSize', sizeConverter($('#uploadFile')[0].files[0].size/1024));
formData.append('file', $('#uploadFile')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'project:uploadFile' %}",
    type: 'post',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
});
```

The issue is probably here `$('#uploadFile')[0]`. It should be `$('#uploadFile')[0].files[0]`. Also, url syntax has an error with quotes.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Method not allowed(POST)". Is it not going to the correct place or something?

Comment: I don't know. Give me a minute to test. What's your url in urls?

Comment: url(r'bienbox/bucket/uploadFile/$',views.uploadFile.as_view(),name='uploadFile'),. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have tested this code and copy/pasted your view and it works. You're probably getting Method not allowed because some other url is consuming your uploadFile url.

Comment: Btw, now when I submit the form it redirects to the same page. Shouldn't preventDefault() work?

Comment: It should. Check for typos in your javascript code.

Comment: Ok, whenever I use FormData() and append any data to it then nothing works anymore. just having the variable var fileData = FormData(); causes everything to stop. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` in your ajax. And handle the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` with `.append(..)` method.

```
$('.uploadForm').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var fileSize = $('#uploadFile')[0].files[0].size/1024;
  var fileName = $('#uploadFile')[0].files[0].name;
  var realSize = sizeConverter(fileSize);

  var fileData = new FormData($('#uploadFile').get(0));
  fileData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
  //fileData.append('fileData', fileData);
  fileData.append('realSize', realSize);

  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'project:uploadFile' %}",
    type: "POST",
    data: fileData,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

> For `generic.TemplateView` you have only `get` method implemented. You should implement `post` method to allow post form or try to use `generic.FormView`.

Comment: Now I'm getting "Method not allowed(POST)". Is it not going to the correct place or something?

Comment: how about adding `http_method_names = ['get', 'post']` in your view, see this https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/

Comment: Tested now, still the same. Cheers for your help. I will try to get this working somehow.

Comment: Please check my original post. There I copied my views.py with post method included. As I mentioned, I can post the form with text only('fileSize'). I can't post the file still.

Comment: great answer - after hours of debugging